# get item index in Flot pie chart

Tags: flot, pie-chart

I'm Using flot.pie.js and flot.tooltip.js libraries to draw a Pie chart.

I need to Access the index of the Item that the mouse is on.

My data format is:

```
var data = 
[
   {data: 51, label: 'LabelA'},  // As first item
   {data: 49, label: 'labelB'},  // As second item
];
```

I'm guessing I have to modify toolTipOpts:{content...}. Can anyone please describe the code of function that is passed to 'content' for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a function callback to the content parameter.  The `flotItem` parameter contains a `seriesIndex` property:

```
content: function(label, xval, yval, flotItem){
    return flotItem.seriesIndex + '';
},
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XtwUnPcOJHQcZbi4dLXR?p=preview).